# CSS :before content - Use image and add wrapping

Tags: html, css, dom

How do I add a line break after the content image? My css is below, its not working:

```
#login-window:before {
    content: url(images/logo.png),"\a";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work, use space between each element, then use pre-wrap.

```
#login-window:before {
    content: url(images/logo.png) "\a";
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep the content blank and style it like you would a normal div:

```
#login-window:before {
  background: url(images/logo.png) no-repeat;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not working because CSS properties don't read regular expressions in that way, since you are managing a pseudo-element you should leave it blank the content and change the display, if you want a line break you should be doing somethin' like this:

```
#login-window:before {
  content: '';
  background: url(images/logo.png) no-repeat;
  display: block;
  height: 80px; /* Set it to your needs */
  width: 80px; /* Set it to your needs */
  padding-bottom: 12px; /* To leave a blank space inside the box*/
}
```